# Why don't control events fire on base interface?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

This one is weird.  I've got a UITextView control called `txtNotes`, and I want to consume `Scrolled` events, so I do this:

```
txtNotes.Scrolled += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
    "Scrolled".Debug();
};
```

And this works fine; the debug message prints as expected.  But I have a helper function that does something to `UIScrollView`, which `UITextView` inherits from.  So I'm doing the equivalent of this:

```
UIScrollView uv = txtNotes;

uv.Scrolled += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
    "Scrolled".Debug();
};
```

And this **DOES NOT WORK**: the event handler is never called.  And elsewhere I have a control of type `UIScrollView` (**NOT** a type that inherits from `UIScrollView`), and I **CAN** get events from it.  So it seems like base class events don't fire on subclasses when they are typed as the base class.

This doesn't make any sense to me, and really feels like a bug in Monotouch or maybe the underlying iOS.  Can anyone confirm this, or tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix/work around it?

Comment: Instead of using the C# event, does the equivalent `UIScrollViewDelegate` work instead?

Comment: I have just tried the exact same thing as in your example and it worked perfectly. Are you using an old version of MonoTouch?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers: No, I get the same thing.  The delegate works when attached to the UITextView, but NOT when attached to the *same object* cast to UIScrollView.

Comment: @Blounty: I was using an old version, but just to be sure I upgraded to the latest Xamarin Studio and I still get the problem.  Do you have the source code you used so I can see what might be different?

Comment: So can you just cast to a `UITextView` and it starts working? I suspect this might be an issue with the MonoTouch implementation details underneath.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers: I could cast that way, but that defeats the whole purpose on having a generic helper method that works on instances of type UIScrollView.

Comment: I'm just asking if it fixes it. If so, I bet someone from Xamarin could fill us in on what is going on.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers: It does fix it.  That's the exact issue (bug?) that I'm reporting.  I've asked Xamarin about this and I hope they give some insight soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `UITextView` provides:

```
public new event EventHandler Scrolled
```

the **`new`** keyword hides the base `UIScrollView.Scrolled` event - making them two separate implementations. IOW if you set one then the other is not set. That's how .NET works.

But why is there a **`new`** ? The reasons are a bit complex. Providing strongly typed events is only possible by creating an internal `*Delegate` type as glue code. That works well for 99% of the time but has a few [drawbacks](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/events-vs-objective-c-delegates/).

In this case the internal `*Delegate` type won't be identical if a `UIScrollView` or an `UITextView` is used - and inheritance could not be used (and the reason for it escapes my mind tonight :-).

However I'm surprised that using `[Weak]Delegate` properties did not work. I see why, it's the same **`new`**, but I can't recall a reason for this one... Need to investigate :)

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation.  Now I understand what's going on and that I'm not crazy.  But now I'm not sure how to work around the problem.  It's much cleaner to be able to write code that works on any instance of a base type, and not to have to write different versions for UIScrollView, UITextView, UIWebView, etc.  Can you suggest a strategy for handling this Event/Delegate issue in a clean way?

Comment: I'm looking into this... will update my answer after a few tests.